# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.yml'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting below error for the **Spring Cloud** project. In this project I am not doing anything special other than reading the .properties files from the GIT.

Please guide on what else need to be corrected out here ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.yml'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:535) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:494) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:462) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$4(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:444) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$5(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:443) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:440) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:331) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:196) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:183) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:169) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:358) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at pluralsight.demo.PluralsightSpringcloudM2ConfigserverGitApplication.main(PluralsightSpringcloudM2ConfigserverGitApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block collection
 in 'reader', line 17, column 17:
                    - "*/perf"
                    ^
expected <block end>, but found Key
 in 'reader', line 18, column 17:
                    uri: https://github.com/rseroter ... 
                    ^
```

How we can solved the below error ?
**application.yml**

```
---
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls

          search-paths:
          - 'station*'
          repos:
            perf:
              pattern: 
                - "*/perf"
                uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf

                search-paths:
                - 'station*'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing quotes

```
---
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls

          search-paths:
          - 'station*'
          repos:
            perf:
              pattern: 
                - */perf ##as it was trying to match the whole pattern
                uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf

                search-paths:
                - 'station*'
```

If still not works, please try the below

```
repos:
  perf:
    pattern: xx*/perf, */pref ##as the fist character can't be a wild card but it can accept multiple value.
    uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf
```

Also it is important to look for correct indentation while working with yml files.

Answer (score 23):

This error indicates an issue with the formatting of the application.yml
You can validate your yml file online:
http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: If we use sublime, we could pick pretty yaml, which can easily set the syntax correct

Answer (score 5):

In case the other answers didn't help and you are using IntelliJ like me, try reloading the Gradle project, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got that error today, and I didn't understand at first because the indentation of my conf was good. Then I realized that was because the encoding of my `application.yml` was "*Microsoft something*" (suggested by IntelliJ, don't remember exactly). I just copied my conf, pasted it in SublimeText, deleted my `application.yml`, then recreated a new file with the same name (so `application.yml`), copied what was in SublimeText, then pasted it in my new file.
Apparently the default encoding fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and fix it already. If the application.yml file is well done, you can try to empty your maven repository(at Maven/repository).then do maven update at your project and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the second `search-paths`, I think you put that in there by mistake. But for the error messages in line 17 & 18, that's an easy fix:

Add another dash to the line containing the uri, so that it looks like that:

```
repos:
        perf:
          pattern: 
            - */perf ##as it was trying to match the whole pattern
            - uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf
```

What comes after `pattern:` is supposed to be a list and you need to prefix the items with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue... the one of the reason is not giving proper spacing in yaml file. I have resolved as below -

Example -

```
incorrect one ->
    RESERVATION:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
        slidingWindowSize: 100   --> this parameter have unnecessary spaces at beginning

the correct one is ->

    RESERVATION:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 100      --> correct as spaces at beginning removed
```

Refer below image -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If, in the future, anyone else has a problem with the coding, I ask you to check the comments in the application.yml

I have a grails application that runs normally with grails run-app, but the .war file was not running.

I found that a link, in a comment, was causing the exception below, even with yml without errors.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.yml'
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:473)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:443)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:425)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:425)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:422)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:202)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:186)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:176)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:340)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:97)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:458)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:445)
        at transporteLegal.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:57)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:218)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:176)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:136)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanFlowScalarNonSpaces(ScannerImpl.java:1861)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanFlowScalar(ScannerImpl.java:1841)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchFlowScalar(ScannerImpl.java:1027)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchDouble(ScannerImpl.java:1009)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:394)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingValue.produce(ParserImpl.java:586)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:124)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:236)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:227)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:215)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:144)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:236)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:227)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:215)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:144)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:85)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:123)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:547)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:134)
        at org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:94)
        at org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:59)
        at org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:497)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:125)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:183)
        ... 62 common frames omitted
```